# Cannot make Nav Horizontal

Tags: html, css, navbar, dreamweaver

I've been working on this for ages and am trying everything under the sun to try to figure out how to make this navbar horizontal I've previously done it because I copied and pasted this from an old website I've done but it doesn't seem to be working. what am I doing wrong?  Ive done floating to the left display inline all that stuff. is it possible that I have something that could be overriding it? 
PS. I'm working in Dreamweaver and using some of the bootstrap codings if that helps.

```
<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">webshop</a></li>
   </ul> 
 </nav>
```

/*Nav Formatting*/

```
.navbar-nav {
  width: 20%;
text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}
.navbar-nav .nav > lu {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}
```

/*Nav Formatting: Hover animation*/

```
.navbar-nav li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.navbar-nav li:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  background-color: #ABE1DB;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.4s ease 0.4s;
  transition: height 0.4s ease 0.4s;
}

.navbar-nav li:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  background-color: #ABE1DB;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.4s ease 0.4s;
  transition: height 0.4s ease 0.4s;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover:before, li:hover:after {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover a {
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0.4s;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0.4s;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover a:before, li:hover a:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-nav a {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 40px;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight:normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #ABE1DB;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
}
.navbar-nav a:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ABE1DB;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease;
  transition: width 0.4s ease;
}

.navbar-nav a:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ABE1DB;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease;
  transition: width 0.4s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set

```
.navbar-nav{
     width: 20%; 
}
```

How can it expand? Try

```
.navbar-nav {
    width: 100%; 
}
```

```css
/*Nav Formatting*/

.navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav>li {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-nav .nav>lu {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
}


/*Nav Formatting: Hover animation*/

.navbar-nav li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.navbar-nav li:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  background-color: #ABE1DB;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.4s ease 0.4s;
  transition: height 0.4s ease 0.4s;
}

.navbar-nav li:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  background-color: #ABE1DB;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.4s ease 0.4s;
  transition: height 0.4s ease 0.4s;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover:before,
li:hover:after {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover a {
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0.4s;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0.4s;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover a:before,
li:hover a:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-nav a {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 40px;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #ABE1DB;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
}

.navbar-nav a:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ABE1DB;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease;
  transition: width 0.4s ease;
}

.navbar-nav a:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ABE1DB;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease;
  transition: width 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<!--- Navbar --->

<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">webshop</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ul` is to small. That's why it will press it together. Try

```
ul.nav.navbar-nav {
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The outer container `.navbar-nav` was styled with 20% width. This forced the inner elements to wrap because there was not enough space. A width of 100% is not need here because `<nav>` is an block element.
2. If you only have 4 four inner elements, you can give them a `width of 25%` combined with `floating left` to stack them next to each other.
3. Add a [clearfix class](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) or `overflow:hidden` (quick and dirty!) to the outer container to make sure it visally wraps the inner elements.
4. Please see my updated code snippet for reference:

```css
/*Nav Formatting*/

.navbar-nav {
}

.navbar-nav li {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav .nav > ul {
  float: right; 
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
}


/*Nav Formatting: Hover animation*/

.navbar-nav li {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar-nav li:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  background-color: #ABE1DB;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.4s ease 0.4s;
  transition: height 0.4s ease 0.4s;
}

.navbar-nav li:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  background-color: #ABE1DB;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.4s ease 0.4s;
  transition: height 0.4s ease 0.4s;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover:before,
li:hover:after {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover a {
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0.4s;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0.4s;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover a:before,
li:hover a:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-nav a {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 40px;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #ABE1DB;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
}

.navbar-nav a:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ABE1DB;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease;
  transition: width 0.4s ease;
}

.navbar-nav a:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ABE1DB;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease;
  transition: width 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<!--- Navbar --->

<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">webshop</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Changing the width seems to change the size of hover over my nav.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/*Nav Formatting*/

.navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav >li {
  float: right;
}

.navbar-nav .nav > ul {
  float: right;
}


/*Nav Formatting: Hover animation*/

.navbar-nav li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.navbar-nav li:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  background-color: #ABE1DB;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.4s ease 0.4s;
  transition: height 0.4s ease 0.4s;
}

.navbar-nav li:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 2px;
  height: 0;
  background-color: #ABE1DB;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.4s ease 0.4s;
  transition: height 0.4s ease 0.4s;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover:before,
li:hover:after {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover a {
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0.4s;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease 0.4s;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover a:before,
li:hover a:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-nav a {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 40px;
  height: 100%;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: #ABE1DB;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease;
}

.navbar-nav a:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ABE1DB;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease;
  transition: width 0.4s ease;
}

.navbar-nav a:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ABE1DB;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease;
  transition: width 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<!--- Navbar --->

<nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">webshop</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```